# Google maps Marker link failure

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My google marker link refuses to function. i click it will not open the link.

```
 // Let's also add a marker while we're at it

                var image = 'images/icons/mapicon.png';                 
                var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.419659, -77.4126419),                   
                    map: map,
                    icon: image,
                    url: 'https://www.google.com'
        });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        window.open(marker.url);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your addListener is pointing to **marker** variable, but your marker is defined as **beachMarker**.